# How to calculate the sum of a column in an MS Access table for a given date (a single day, month or year)

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb.net-2010

I have a table in Access in a custom format saved as `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt` , Also A form in VB.NET 2010, I get a specific day, month and year with no problem but the problem comes when I want to query the sum of a column named value depending on a specific month or day or year....

The table is like:

```
+-----+-----------+-------------------------+
| id  |     value |       date              |
+-----+-----------+-------------------------+
| id1 |      1499 | 01/01/2012 07:30:11 p.m.|
| id2 |      1509 | 11/02/2012 07:30:11 p.m.|
| id3 |      1611 | 21/10/2012 07:30:11 p.m.|
| id1 |      1115 | 11/10/2012 07:30:11 p.m.|
| id1 |      1499 | 17/05/2012 07:30:11 p.m.|
| id2 |      1709 | 11/06/2012 07:30:11 p.m.|
| id3 |      1911 | 30/07/2012 07:30:11 p.m.|
| id1 |      1015 | 01/08/2012 07:30:11 p.m.|
| id1 |      1000 | 11/05/2012 07:30:11 p.m.|
|+-----+-----------+------------------------+
```

So I Know the query

`SELECT SUM(value) FROM mytable WHERE date in='01/05/2012 00:00:00'` ...

How to tell the query I want the month of May so I would get 1499+1000= 2499

Or how to tell I want the year 2012 so I would get the sum of all the table

Which would be the correct syntax...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not standard SQL, but if you're using Access this should always work:

```
 SELECT SUM([Value]) FROM Mytable WHERE Year([Date])=2012 and Month([Date])=5
```

or this, if you just want to filter the year:

```
 SELECT SUM([Value]) FROM Mytable WHERE Year([Date])=2012
```

Answer (score 2):

If the data type of your "date" field is Date/Time, your query can use date literals to specify the range of rows to evaluate.  Use yyyy-mm-dd format for the date literals in the query, and enclosed them in the `#` character to inform the db engine they are Date/Time values.

For May of 2012:

```
SELECT SUM([value])
FROM mytable
WHERE [date] >= #2012-05-01# AND [date] < #2012-06-01#;
```

For all of 2012:

```
SELECT SUM([value])
FROM mytable
WHERE [date] >= #2012-01-01# AND [date] < #2013-01-01#;
```

I enclosed both `date` and `value` in square brackets because both are reserved words.

Note I assumed your `[date]` field is indexed.  If that is correct, the queries I suggested should allow the db engine to quickly identify which rows match your selection criteria.  Without an available index, the db engine would have to perform a full table scan --- examine every row in the table to determine which of them match the criteria.  When it comes to performance, "full table scan == BAD" and "indexed retrieval == BETTER".  And when the db engine can use an index, the retrieval speed can easily be an order of magnitude faster.  So if you don't already have an index on your `[date]` field, you should consider adding one.

A related point is you should design your queries so the db engine can use the index.  If your `WHERE` clause includes functions, such as the two examples below, which require the db engine examine every row in the table, it can't take advantage of indexing ... and you're essentially back to a full table scan.

- `WHERE Year([Date])=2012 and Month([Date])=5`
- `WHERE Year([Date])=2012`

This is not much of a concern if your table is small enough.  You might not notice the lag.  But keep this point in mind for when/if the size of your table grows, or when creating similar queries for other large tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a between function to query for a month or year:

```
SELECT SUM(value) FROM mytable WHERE date  between to_date ('01/05/2012', 'yyyy/mm/dd')    AND to_date ('31/05/2012', 'yyyy/mm/dd');
```

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi should work, [look here](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/sql-between.html)

Comment: @Flash that's Access SQL to Oracle (backend). OP hasn't made such a disclosure. My reading is that Access *is* the backend